# S3 public Url accessible only from instance inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to restrict access for my S3 bucket objects to be accessible using the public URL only from instances inside a VPC. Trying to achieve it using Bucket Policy by specifying VPC id. Check the bucket  policy below.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1596618884802",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1596618880986",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<--bucket-name-->",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<--bucket-name-->/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "<--vpd-id-->"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But even after this policy the objects are not accessible from the URL but are accessible using s3 api inside the VPC.

Comment: Found solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539057/restricting-s3-bucket-access-to-a-vpc)