# How to install packages from AWS CodeArtifact for use in AWS Glue Spark jobs?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-codeartifact

**Question**

What should I use for `--index-url` and `--trusted-host` to install Python packages from AWS CodeArtifact in an AWS Glue (Spark) job, when using the method described in the section *Setting up a CodeArtifact mirror of pypi attached to your VPC* of [this AWS Glue Developer Guide page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-pypi.html)?

**Background**

I am attempting to run an AWS Glue Spark job that needs to import private packages.  The packages are available within a repo in AWS CodeArtifact.  I am able to install the packages from an EC2; this question is about installing the package for use in AWS Glue.

I was able to install the packages by specifying the following job parameters:

- `--additional-python-modules` as the package name
- `--python-modules-installer-option` as `--index-url=https://aws:<codeartifact token>@<domain name>-<domain-owner>.d.codeartifact.<region>.com/pypi/<repo name>/simple/`

Problem is that the codeartifact token expires every 12 hours.  So I'm able to get it to work by manually generating the token and replacing it in the job param, but that's not ideal.

[This AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-and-optimize-python-package-management-for-aws-glue-pyspark-jobs-with-aws-codeartifact/) suggests using AWS Step Functions to first get the token, use that to formulate the index URL, then trigger the job and pass it the index URL.  That seems incredibly clunky!

So then I came across that page in the AWS Glue Developer guide which suggests setting up a VPC endpoint for CodeArtifact.  But it's not clear where to get the URLs (which look like S3 URLs) used to specify `--index-url`.

Has anybody solved this problem?

NOTE:  while this question is specifically about what to use for `--index-url`, I'm also open to other approaches to solve the underlying problem of how to install packages from CodeArtifact for use in an AWS Glue job.

Comment: I have an answer ready for this but have reached out to the AWS Glue team to clarify a few questions before I post an answer.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary did you hear back from the AWS Glue team?  Even if not, I'd be curious to know what your thoughts are on this.  Cheers!

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary would be interested to hear your thoughts about this as well

Comment: @teejay Sadly I didn't. I've added my thoughts below!

Comment: @Simon30 Sadly I didn't! I've added my thoughts below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CodeArtifact token expires every 12 hours

[Correct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/tokens-authentication.html), CodeArtifact tokens have a minimum validity of 15 minutes & a maximum validity of 12 hours. There's no 'workaround'.

> This AWS post suggests using AWS Step Functions to first get the token, use that to formulate the index URL, then trigger the job and pass it the index URL. That seems incredibly clunky!

You've discovered the main pain point of using AWS CodeArtifact: there's no auto-refresh capability by default.

Other community workarounds, that don't apply to AWS Glue, have been creating custom Java Gradle plugins to auto refresh, scripts running on a Cron schedule, writing the token to a file & checking the last modified before pulling from the repo etc.

Currently, there isn't a native integration between AWS CodeArtifact & AWS Glue that manages the token lifecycle in the background.

If you want to use CodeArtifact, you **must** generate a new token at most every 12 hours.

With no native integration, the solution mentioned in the blog is a viable one.

> So then I came across that page in the AWS Glue Developer guide which suggests setting up a VPC endpoint for CodeArtifact. But it's not clear where to get the URLs (which look like S3 URLs) used to specify `--index-url`.

AWS know about the lack of a native integration, hence the need for a [*Setting up an Amazon S3 bucket to host a targeted PyPI/simple repo*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-pypi.html#setup-vpc-for-pypi-s3-bucket) section in the docs. Although, the docs are currently *really, really, really bad*.

In this scenario, **you're not using CodeArtifact**.

You're using [`s3pypi`](https://github.com/gorilla-co/s3pypi) to essentially host a Python Package Repository in an S3 bucket. Note there isn't a sync option here between CodeArtifact and the S3 bucket; you have to manually keep the bucket updated with the latest versions of your packages.

`--index-url` is the ['base URL of the Python Package Index'](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-0).

`--trusted-host` is used to ['mark this host or host:port pair as trusted, even though it does not have valid (certificate) or any HTTPS'](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#cmdoption-trusted-host).

In AWS terms, `--index-url` needs to be set to the S3 static website endpoint & `--trusted-host` needs to be set to the S3 static website endpoint without the scheme e.g. `https://`.

And since Glue jobs can run in a VPC, referring to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794315/4800344) like this should allow you to lock the package repository down to just your private VPC.

Comment: just to clarify: you referenced "Setting up an Amazon S3 bucket to host a targeted PyPI/simple repo" in your answer, but there is a section below that which talks about CodeArtifact ("Setting up a CodeArtifact mirror of pypi attached to your VPC").  Are you saying that even this actually refers not to CodeArtifact but to S3?

Comment: @teejay That is for mirroring the PyPi repo in CodeArtifact which basically takes you back to square one :)

Comment: Huh, that seems pointless if one can't then (easily) access CodeArtifact from Glue. 
 Thank you @ErmiyaEskandary.  I'll accept this answer for now because, while it doesn't resolve my underlying problem, it does at least flesh out what the AWS limitations are and supplements the poor AWS documentation, and will hopefully save someone else trying to figure out something that can't be done.  Hopefully AWS makes their documentation easier to understand, and allows seamless connection between Glue and CodeArtifact.